# jQuery ajax sequencing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have one ajax call that deletes an object in the db and I want to the sequence two other ajax calls to update lists.  I have tried understanding .promise(),.deferred() and just cant get it working.  Below are my details, any help appreciated.

```
    var url = "./rest00/deleteVendor/" + shortName;
    $.get(url, updateVendorsXMLs);  //unique for mgt portal
    var url00 = "./rest00/subscribersXLMs";
    //$.get(url00,sxml00);
    var url01 = "./rest00/vendors";
    //$.get(url01, updateVendors);
    $.get(url00).when(function(data){
        sxml00(data);
        return $.get(url01)}).when(function(data1){
        updateVendors(data1);
        return true;
    }).fail(console.log.bind.console);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing with JQuery ajax is that it doesn't return a http object that allows to chain methods as I think you want, something like `$.get(url, data).then(respo => respo.data).get(data => data.respo)` an on... you would have to put them inside the response or just after it to refresh after error/success.

```
$.get(url, data)
  .then(respo => {
  //hadle data
  $.get(url2, data2).then(respo => handle(respo)).catch(err => handle(error));
  $.get(url2, data2).then(respo => handle(respo)).catch(err => handle(error));
})
 .catch(err => {
   //handle error
});
```

Or use other library like axios, that allows to handle array of requests and it'll do the job.